# Mac OS X HHKB <C-left> not captured by GNU Emacs

Tags: osx

I've been using GNU Emacs and Mac OS X (Early 2015, 10.13.2) and HHKB works well.

Several days before I bought a new Macbook Pro(2018, 10.14.1) and plugged the same HHKB. Everything works fine but the `<C-left>` (or Control + Fn + ;) and `<C-right>` not captured by Emacs.

I've tried that the `<C-up/down/left/right>` on the old Macbook and those keys can be captured by Emacs, but on the new Macbook, these keys are intercepted by OS and not captured by Emacs.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't use the English version of Mac, but I found the shortcut panel of keyboard in system preferences has `C-up/down/left/right` defined. So uncheck the boxes make the Emacs works again.

[image]

Comment: If this resolved the problem, please accept your own answer so we can close the post.